# My Java Code keeps returning wrong values?

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans, return

```
public class CirclePlus implements Relatable {
    public double radius = 0;
    final double PI = 3.14159;

CirclePlus(){}

public CirclePlus(double radius) {
    radius = radius;
}

public double getArea() {
    return PI * (radius * radius);
}

public double isLargerThan(Relatable other) {
    CirclePlus otherCirc = (CirclePlus)other;
    if (this.getArea() < otherCirc.getArea())
        return -1;           
    else if (this.getArea() > otherCirc.getArea())
        return 1;            
    else
        return 0;

}
```

/// Main class below

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    CirclePlus c1 = new CirclePlus(50);
    CirclePlus c2 = new CirclePlus(0);

    if(c1.isLargerThan(c2) == 1) {
      System.out.println("c1 is bigger!");
  }
  else
      System.out.println("c1 has the same size as that of c2 or smaller than"
              + " c2!");

}
```

Output is always:

```
"c1 has the same size as that of c2 or smaller than"
```

No matter what I change the radius of the 2 circles to.

This is my code, it keeps returning 0 in the final else statement but even when the conditions are met in the if/else if statements, it ignores them and just goes to the bottom and returns 0;

Can you help me to fix this? Also, just so I can learn more, can you explain why java is doing this?

Just the help will be okay too, thanks so much!

Comment: What is this code???IsLargerThan should return a boolean..... jdk has already some methods for that

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ True, the method signature is more like an implement of a Comparator.

Comment: Hey guys, I changed it up and added plenty of more information. I'm so sorry about that I'm new here so it's my fault I barely added any information. I hope that information helps out and you can help me to understand the problem clearly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs in the following piece of code:

```
[...]
public double radius = 0;
[...]
public CirclePlus(double radius) {
    radius = radius;
}
```

Here, Java tries to assign the local method variable `radius` to itself, which has no effect on your class member variable `radius`.

To avoid this problem, you have to either qualify the left hand side of the assignment like this

```
public CirclePlus(double radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
}
```

or use a different name for the local variable like this

```
public CirclePlus(double r) {
    radius = r;
}
```

so that Java can distinguish the local method variable from the class variable.

Some other minor points: your class variable `radius` should be private rather than public and your `isLargerThan` method should return an int instead of a double.

Also, it would be more logical if a method called `isLargerThan` would return a boolean. You could also implement the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html?is-external=true) interface:

```
int compareTo(CirclePlus other) {
    return Double.compare(this.getArea(), other.getArea());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much @Modus Tollens that was highly helpful I cannot thank you enough for that well written response!